# Creating a dataframe from list and existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I have a dataframe in the form of

```
column 1 column 2 column 3
```

And I would like to add values to it.
I have a list which I would like to add which is in the form of:

```
a= [['Master Vithal', ' Vithal Zubeida'], ['Firozshah Mistry', ' B Irani'], ['Grigor']]
```

How do I add elements in this list so that a[0] will go to column 1 and so on.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to add elements of list `a` at the end of the dataframe, as follows:

```
import numpy as np

cols = ['column 1', 'column 2',  'column 3']    # enter your selected columns here
df.loc[len(df), cols] = np.array(a, dtype='object')[0:len(cols)]
```

**Demo**

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['column 1', 'column 2',  'column 3'])
a= [['Master Vithal', ' Vithal Zubeida'], ['Firozshah Mistry', ' B Irani'], ['Grigor']]

cols = ['column 1', 'column 2',  'column 3']
df.loc[len(df), cols] = np.array(a, dtype='object')[0:len(cols)]

print(df)

                           column 1                      column 2  column 3
0  [Master Vithal,  Vithal Zubeida]  [Firozshah Mistry,  B Irani]  [Grigor]
```

Comment: This produces this error: could not broadcast input array from shape (9) into shape (6)

Comment: @FafamKurac123  Are `column 1` `column 2` `column 3` all you have in the dataframe ?  Or some other columns else ?

Comment: Oh right I may have some other columns

Comment: @FafamKurac123  Edited solution to cater for if there are some other columns.  Please retry.

Comment: @FafamKurac123  Let me know how's the edited solution works for your dataframe with extra columns?

Comment: @FafamKurac123  Please give feedback and see any fine-tuning need.  Thanks!